# White space when hide bottom bar on push

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I have a tabBarController and when I push a view controller I am hiding the bottom bar to not show the tabBar in the second view controller. The problem is that I see a white space for a moment.

This is de code I am using to push the view controller

```
VerResultadoViewController *controller = (VerResultadoViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ver_resultado"];
controller.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES ;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

This is the white space:

[image: White space]

Answer (score 0):

Call the `hideBottomBarWhenPushed` in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` (can't remember what the correct one is; you have to experiment) of the controller you are pushing.